# Elementos fugindo do mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery

pessoal alguém sabe algum plugin ou como faço um efeito no javascript parecido com esse?

https://newtemplate.net/demo/event4/template/particles.html

Porem quero o seguinte quero que varios elementos svg corram do mouse. se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Comment: O plugin usado no site é esse: https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Comment: Você poderia ter descoberto no nome do plugin simplesmente apertando F12 e lendo o código da página.

Answer (score 2):

Esse efeito é feito por partículas em um `<canvas>`, neste caso, o site que enviou usa este plugin:
https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Basta importar o script

```
<script src="particles.js"></script>
```

E injetar os dados em uma div qualquer com o código

```
particlesJS('ID_ELEMENTO', {
    "particles": {
        "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
                "enable": true,
                "value_area": 800
            }
        }
        //Outras Opções...
    },
}, function () {

});
```

A lista de opções completa pode ser acessada aqui:
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Aqui tem um artigo interessante sobre o uso de partículas com canvas:
https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/desenhando-particulas-usando-html5-canvas